# How to create an "Adjust time" HTML form without using HTML5 input type="time"?

Tags: html, time, forms

I'm trying to create an HTML form, allowing a user to adjust/set the server-time (clock/date).  This would seem like a perfect candidate for the HTML5 `<input type="time">`, however this doesn't allow 24h input apparently. Being an HTML "n00b", I tried to Google a solution, but keep turning up results using exactly that input. So how can I do it?

I also need to adjust the date, which also seems obvious for `<input type="date">`.

Best regards,
Soren

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically this has been done in the past using a series of drop-down SELECTs, one for each unit.

Comment: Could you please be more specific, I don't quite follow?

Comment: <select name="hour"><option>1</option>....</select> <select name="minute"><option>1</option>....</select>

Comment: Ok, I see. I was hoping more for being able to add some reg-ex to a text-input. Why is the <select> solution preferred?

Comment: So you don't have to write a parser for text input.